# vim - show part of a file from line to line

Tags: vim

Is it possible in vim to show part of a file from a given line to another line (say file a.txt from line 10 to line 25) in a buffer? Is it possible also to edit it and write it back on the file by removing the content (line 10 to 25), then starting from the start line (line 10) place the current buffer?

I wish to edit part of files from line ranges I specify without opening the whole file. I need this for useability purposes, not for performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [NrrwRgn plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) does this; the editor feature originates from Emacs. You can use `:NarrowRegion` to edit a range of lines in a scratch buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it in vim alone, but if I had a problem like that, I would split the file:

```
head -n 10 file > file1
tail -n +11 | head 15 > file2
tail -n +16 > file3
```

Then edit the middle file

```
 vim file2
```

and concatenate the files again:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > file
```

Of course, with a little function helper you could do it with one command.

If the problem is that you don't like to view the whole file (rather than because the file is very big), then define folds that hide the rest of the file:

```
1Gv9jzf16jvGzf
```

(Explanation: `1Gv9j`- go to the top, start a visual block, go 9 lines down; `zf` create a fold, `16j` go down to line 26, `vG` make a visual block from line 26 to the end, `zf` fold the rest of the file)

Comment: Creating intermediate files will be hard to maintain with time. Up-voted for the the normal mode command and explanation. But I would use 26G instead of 16j to make it easier (as it will be hard with large line numbers).